# 300% of my CPU is being used?

Tags: macos, cpu, activity-monitor

I ran a Java applet, and it used over 200% of my CPU....

[image: %CPU 273.5]

It actually rose to over 400% after I took the screenshot.

How is this possible? Can someone explain why Activity Monitor shows a task as using more than 100% of my CPU?

Comment: Please refer to this thread. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/226281/how-does-my-dual-core-i5-in-my-macbook-pro-have-more-than-400-cpu-usage/226702#226702

Answer (score 7):

The CPU percentages shown in Activity Monitor are 100% for each virtual core. If you have a quad core processor with hyperthreading, 'real' 100% is 800% in Activity Monitor.

Comment: Is this because of hyper threading that each core gains up to 200% per core?

Comment: How can I find out what my maximum activity monitor CPU% could possibly be?

Comment: I've never seen higher than 400 in Activity Monitor, but when I open the CPU History Window there are slots for 8 cores and all of them have some activity (although the cores labelled 2, 4, 6, and 8 have almost no usage)